# Glide IllegalStateException: Already released from State verifier

Tags: java, android, android-glide, androidx

After migrating to androidx and updating the glide version to 4.9.0 I've been getting the stateException crash from stateVerifier from Glide. I'm not able to reproduce this issue on my physical device.

I'm using glide with okhttp to load images in a viewpager.

After doing a quick search on glide issues there are open issues with the same exception but no solutions.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Stateverifier

## Dependencies versions

```
androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0
com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0
com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.9.0
```

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already released
       at com.bumptech.glide.util.pool.StateVerifier$DefaultStateVerifier.throwIfRecycled + 46(StateVerifier.java:46)
       at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.begin + 236(SingleRequest.java:236)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.resumeRequests + 128(RequestTracker.java:128)
       at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.resumeRequests + 292(RequestManager.java:292)
       at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onStart + 317(RequestManager.java:317)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStart + 51(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:51)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStart + 182(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:182)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart + 2577(Fragment.java:2577)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 909(FragmentManagerImpl.java:909)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1227(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1293(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange + 2612(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2612)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart + 2578(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2578)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart + 257(FragmentController.java:257)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart + 533(FragmentActivity.java:533)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart + 176(AppCompatActivity.java:176)
       at com.nis.app.ui.base.BaseAppCompatActivity.onStart + 54(BaseAppCompatActivity.java:54)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart + 1355(Instrumentation.java:1355)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart + 7001(Activity.java:7001)
       at android.app.Activity.performRestart + 7075(Activity.java:7075)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume + 7080(Activity.java:7080)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3740(ActivityThread.java:3740)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3810(ActivityThread.java:3810)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1721(ActivityThread.java:1721)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 108(Handler.java:108)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 206(Looper.java:206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6784(ActivityThread.java:6784)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 240(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 852(ZygoteInit.java:852)
```

## Crash Distribution

[image]

## Runtime Execption

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {package/package.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already released
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3770(ActivityThread.java:3770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3810(ActivityThread.java:3810)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1721(ActivityThread.java:1721)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 108(Handler.java:108)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 206(Looper.java:206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6784(ActivityThread.java:6784)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 240(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 852(ZygoteInit.java:852)
```

Comment: If you are unable to fix this issue later then consider downgrading to 4.8.0

Comment: I was earlier using glide 4.4.0 issue contains in 4.8.0 as well.